# Can't understand function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, parallax.js

Hello everyone I am frontend beginner, so for me parallax scrolling is very interesting area, and now I start learning it. 
I am watching tutorials and read a lot of stuff for it, but still I am filing as a beginner. 
And now I have this:

```
if (wScroll > $('.clothes-pics').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) { 

$('.clothes-pics figure').each(function(i){

setTimeout(function(){ 

  $('.clothes-pics figure').eq(i).addClass('is-showing'); 
  }, (300 * (Math.exp(i * 0.15))) - 700); 
  }); 

}
```

So here in this example i don't understand the **(300 * (Math.exp(i * 0.15))) - 700);**   code before it I can understand 85%, but here i don't know what is what, and  I am really confused. 
If anyone can explain it to me i will be very thankful. 
And If someone know some good tutorial for parallax it will be very welcome.

Comment: that's a maths equation ...

Comment: I can't tell you much about parallax scrolling, but I can tell you that that piece of code is an expression that is calculating the exponential function of the value i*0.15, multiplying it by 300, and substracting 700 from it. 

The result of this operation will **delay** the execution of the previous code by its result in milliseconds.

Look at tutorials on the setTimeout function, to understand what it is doing. 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Did you set 300 and 700 yourself, or did they come in the example you are following?

Answer (score 2):

It's the `timeOut` value for the `setTimeout(callback, timeout)` function.

The `Math.exp(i * 0.15)` means that, depending on the index, an [exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) of `i*0.15`, which is the same as `e^(i * 0.15)`, where *i* is the value and *e* is [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29).

Interesting way of calculating the `timeOut`. Here's a list of values for `(i) => { return (300 * (Math.exp(i * 0.15))) - 700); }` to give you an idea of what a larger index value means for that `timeOut`:

```
1        =>        -351.449727182
2        =>        -295.042357727
3        =>        -229.506344353
10       =>         644.506721101
100      =>         980704511.742
1,000    =>         4.1811287*(10^67)
```

A very strange way to wait a (sometimes negative) quantity of time before adding a class based on element index, basically.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation part belongs to setTimeout(function(){.

All it does is calculate the milliseconds the system will wait before executing this line:

$('.clothes-pics figure').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');

[Sauce](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Simply follow the brackets and you'll see that **(300 * (Math.exp(i * 0.15))) - 700);** is a parameter for the setTimeout function, all you'll have to do now is google the function and see what that parameter does.
Hope this helps :)